# Mongodb c++ driver: string encoding

Tags: c++, unicode, mongodb

During working on one c++ project we decided to use MongoDB database for storing some data of our application. I have spent a week linking and compiling c++ driver, and its works now. But it is one trouble: strings like

```
bob.append("name", "some text with cyrilic symbols абвгд");
```

are added incorrectly and after extracting from database look like 4-5 chinese symbols.

I have found no documentation about unicode using in mongodb, so I can not understand how to write unicode to database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example, and the [example code in the C++ tutorial on mongodb.org](http://www.mongodb.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=133415) work fine for me on Ubuntu 11.10. My locale is en_US.UTF-8, and I the source files I create are UTF-8.

MongoDB stores data in BSON, and [BSON strings are UTF-8](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Internationalized+Strings), and UTF-8 can handle any Unicode character (including Cyrillic). I think the C++ API assumes strings are UTF-8 encoded, but I'm not sure.

Here are some ideas:

- If your code above (`bob.append("name"`... etc) is in a C++ source code file, try encoding that file as UTF-8.
- Try inserting Unicode characters via the mongodb shell.